# Recording webcam video . . . pause then continue recording?

Tags: linux, webcam

I need to record video from my webcam, but I need to pause the recording from time to time. Cheese and guvcview record, but the only way to pause is to stop the recording, then restart and new recording, then use video editing software to stitch the separate files together.